# Cocos2d: One layer on top of another - Is it Possible to temporarily deactivate touches for a certain layer/region?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, layer, touches

I have a scene where there is a button. Once I click the button, a rectangular sprite slides in from the left side: http://img255.imageshack.us/img255/9867/slidei.png

Under this shape, there are several touch sensitive buttons. I don't want these to be called when I touch on the rectangular shape. So, as long as the shape remains on the screen, those touches should not respond. Instead, there are several other buttons on top of that brown shape, that respond to touches. How can I manage that?

Is it possible to temporarily deactivate touches for a certain layer in a scene? Has the rectangular shape to be a CCLayer Object on its own?

I know I could create a new scene for that shape that has a transparent background, BUT I still want the button to react to touches:

*When I click that button, the shape slides in. When I click it again, it slides off the screen.*

Answer (score 2):

Depends on if you are using actual button objects or CGRect regions that your touchesBegan method responds to. I agree with GamingHorror that the cleanest approach would be to enable/disable the button objects directly as needed.

However, this is a workable kludge as long as the sliding touch region is a UIView subclass.

Before it slides in you can disable all user touches with:

[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

After your view slides in, you may need to setUserInteractionEnabled:YES on that particular view. When it slides out, you can put it all back with

[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

Answer (score 0):

Like with any user interface, you have to let the objects know whether they are enabled or not. Your best bet is actually to send a message to the button, telling it to turn itself on or off.

Ideally you'll be using a global touch input handler, instead of allowing each individual button or slide to react inputs by themselves. This spells a lot of trouble and extra work. Instead, put all objects that should react to input on the same layer, and register that layer with the touch input handler, which will then forward all touch events to that particular layer and no other.

Comment: I actually use "rects" and check whether a certain point is inside that rect. How could I disable CGRect, or objects in general in cocos2d? About your second mentioning: So should I create an extra layer for my slide-shape, where there are only the buttons that can be pressed once the slide is on-screen? If I have a layer on top of another, will it catch my touch input, so that the layer below doesn't get the touch info?